# WPF app using ExpressionDark theme, want to extend TabItem Header style

Tags: wpf, xaml, themes, datatemplate, tabcontrol

For a WPF app using the ExpressionDark theme, I have a TabControl, and without any modifications, the theme style for the tab control is fine.

However, when I implement a HeaderTemplate via a Style Setter, this seems to override the theme's style for the header template.

What I want to do is to extend the theme's style so that my tab control's header can include an image (in the sample code below it's hard-coded but will ultimately be bound and dynamic).

Is there a way to indicate to the *TabItemHeaderTemplate* or *TabItemHeaderTemplateSelected* items to somehow do a BasedOn from the theme's template?

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.ConfigControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         Background="{DynamicResource WindowBackgroundBrush}">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TabItemHeaderTemplate" >
        <Border>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                <Image Height="32" Width="32"
                       Source="/Assets/Images/WarningIcon.png" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10 0 0 0" FontSize="16" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TabItemHeaderTemplateSelected">
        <Button>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                <Image Height="32" Width="32"
                       Source="/Assets/Images/WarningIcon.png" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10 0 0 0" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TabItemContentTemplate">
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <Style x:Key="TabItemContainerStyle" TargetType="TabItem" >
        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding}"/>
        <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate" 
                Value="{StaticResource TabItemHeaderTemplate}"/>
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding}"/>
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" 
                Value="{StaticResource TabItemContentTemplate}"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate" Value="{StaticResource TabItemHeaderTemplateSelected}" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate" Value="{StaticResource TabItemHeaderTemplate}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid Margin="10">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0 20 0 0">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="Model Name:" Margin="0 5 2 0" Width="100" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Config.ModelName, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="WhiteSmoke" Foreground="DarkBlue" Width="200" />
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="Model Description:" Margin="0 5 2 0" Width="100" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Config.Description, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="WhiteSmoke" Foreground="DarkBlue" Width="600" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>

    <TabControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding Parts}"
                ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TabItemContainerStyle}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedConfigPartViewModel, Mode=TwoWay}"
                Margin="0 40 0 0" />


</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of :

```
<Style x:Key="TabItemContainerStyle" TargetType="TabItem" >
....
....
</Style>
```

Try below code :

```
<Style x:Key="TabItemContainerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TabItem}}" >
....
....
</Style>
```

Or if it does not work, then

Change

```
BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TabItem}}"
```

to

```
BasedOn="{StaticResource NameOfYourStyleDeclaredInTheme}"
```

Comment: Thanks so much, the first option works exactly as I wanted it to!  Really appreciate your help.

Comment: You are welcome and please mark my answer as accepted, so that it can help someone in future.

Comment: I tried to do just that but was informed I needed a point score of 15 or more to do that :(   One final question you may have insight into...in my original code I have the two DataTemplates, one for when an item is selected, the other for a regular tab item (TabItemHeaderTemplate and TabItemHeaderTemplateSelected)...this seems like overkill to just have the font different on one...otherwise they are identical.  Is there a better way to do this based on the IsSelected style trigger?  Thanks again.  ps  Just figured out had to click checkmark to set as accepted answer, I had tried the up arrow.

Comment: OK, I will try it and let you know.

Comment: I have tried it. But I can't achieve it. Sorry. I think you should ask another question for that.